# Chrome Browser API (for a browser extension)

Tags: api, google-chrome

I have problem with using the Chrome API the api call i'm using is chrome.storage.sync.get and i was using this to try and get a variable in memory  and when returning the variable it returns [object Object] in the Chrome console which should'nt happen it should return a number depending on what found there
Here is my code

```
//Get index variable
 chrome.storage.sync.get("index_value", function (data1) 
 {
 Get_value(data1)
 });
 function Get_value(value)
 {
    index = value;
    console.log("Fetched index value is" + value);
 }
```

More information:

The variable in memory is just a decimal number e.g 1

I am using the chrome.storage.sync.set API call to save the variable

The variable name is index

The variable index keeps track of array locations e.g array[index]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) `chrome.storage.sync.get` always returns an object and it should contain a property with your `index_value`!?

So this should get your `index_value`:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("index_value", function (data1) 
 {
 console.log(data1.index_value);
 });
```

Also to clarify you only see `[object Object]` in your console log because you do string concatenation instead of logging the object by itself like this:

```
console.log("Fetched index value is", value);
```

That will display the expandable object in your console, notice the `,` instead of `+` so you log two values instead of a single string.

Comment: Does this code automatically assign the local index variable with the value found in memory? This code at first seems to work but it doesn't seem to assign the value found in memory to the local variable index.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "variable in memory" all variables are stored in memory. In my answer I didn't use your `Get_value` function, because it is not doing anything and useless if your real code is like your question and you want to keep it like that just use `index = value.index_value;` (value is a object in that case). Also you sould define local variables with `var index = ...`or `let index = ...` (ES6).